# Product Attributes Not Loading

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm adding a "Most Viewed" section to our website.

While the Product URL is loading correctly, all other attributes (image, product name, price, etc) are not.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class=" most_viewed">
<?php     $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = 5;//count($_products->getItems()); echo $_collectionSize; ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>
<div class="category-products">
<ul class="products-grid">
    <?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
  <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">

            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>

                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
    </li>
<?php $i++; endforeach; $kol = $_collectionSize; ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create attribute then

1)make select display list page yes

2)assign to product group

3)provide some value

4)reindexing

5) add in phtml where you want to display , your case might be ( echo $_product->getMostViewed() ).